# Hide option when selected by another Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I have two select's who uses the same list. When i choose the option "Foo" from select A the same option "Foo" must be hidden on select B. Any ideia how to do it with AngularJS ? I'm trying something like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        Testemunha 1 :
    </label>
    <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
            ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        Testemunha 2 :
    </label>
    <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha2" 
            ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha ">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
  $scope.esconderTestemunhaSelecionada = function(obj){
    if($scope.lstTestemunha.includes(obj)){
      $scope.lstTestemunha.style.display = "none";
      return $scope.lstTestemunha;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter on your second select. This will filter the items in the second select such that the item selected in the first does not appear. If you need it to be more complex (for example, this will cause the second select to not have any options until something is selected in the first select which may be an undesirable side effect) you can always write your own custom filter.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectItems = [];
    $scope.selectedItemA = {};
    $scope.selectedItemB = {};
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      $scope.selectItems.push({
        id: i,
        name: 'Item #' + i
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    Select Item A:
    <select ng-model="selectedItemA" ng-options="item as item.name for item in selectItems"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Select Item B:
    <select ng-model="selectedItemB" ng-options="item as item.name for item in selectItems | filter: { id: '!' + selectedItemA.id }"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem not the way that i'd like but works fine.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        Testemunha 1 :
    </label>
    <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
          ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha">
          <option></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        Testemunha 2 :
    </label>
    <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha2" ng-disabled="!notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
                        ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha | filter: {pessoa:{ id: '!' + notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1.pessoa.id }}">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm forcing the user to set the first select and filter the second according to the first.

By the way, sry my poor english.